# how to setContent in Tiny MCE editor in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

After clicking a button I am tranferred to this page. The link passes two state with it. I am destructuring the state using useLocation hook. Everything works fine.

I want when I get to this page I want to set the blogPrompt varible value in the TinyMCE editor.
But I am not able to do it.

i want the code to work as when landing for the first time the the editor text should change. Then if I change the tone the text should change. But it's not working as intended.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
import Tones from "../components/Tones";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function RichTextEditor() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { topic, keywords } = location.state;
  console.log("topic:", topic);
  console.log("keywords:", keywords);
  const tonesArray = ["Informative", "Inspirational", "Humorous", "Analytical"];
  const [selectedTone, setSelectedTone] = useState(tonesArray[0]);

  const tinyApiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_TINY_API_KEY;
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const ansBoxRef = useRef(null);

  const openAIAPiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_KEY;
  const keywordString = keywords.join(", ");
  const blogPrompt = `Write a blog in an ${selectedTone} tone on the topic: "${topic}" and highlight the keywords: ${keywordString}.`;

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (editorRef.current && ansBoxRef.current) {
      const editorContent = editorRef.current.getContent(); // get the content from the editor
      if (!editorContent) {
        console.log("Nothing inside");
        return;
      }
      const text = editorContent.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/)[1]; // the content is inside a <p> tags but it's not a html , it is a string. get the text between <p> </p> tags.
      const finalText = text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ").trim();
      // Update the content of the "Sample Text" div
      APIcall(finalText);
    }
  };

  async function APIcall(prompt) {
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(new Configuration({ apiKey: openAIAPiKey }));
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
    });

    const reply = response.data.choices[0].message.content;
    if (ansBoxRef.current) {
      ansBoxRef.current.innerText = reply;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    console.log('it worked')
    if (editorRef.current) {
      editorRef.current.setContent(blogPrompt);
      console.log("it worked inside the if condition");
      console.log(blogPrompt);
    }
  }, [blogPrompt]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen p-5 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-300 to-emerald-300">
      <Editor
        apiKey={tinyApiKey}
        onInit={(_, editor) => {
          editorRef.current = editor;
        }}
        initialValue="Write something here."
        init={{
          height: 80,
          menubar: false,
          toolbar: false,
          statusbar: false,
        }}
      />

      <Tones
        tonesArray={tonesArray}
        selectedTone={selectedTone}
        setSelectedTone={setSelectedTone}
      />
      <button
        className="block p-2 my-5 mx-auto px-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 text-white rounded"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Generate
      </button>

      <div
        className="bg-gray-100 p-5 flex-grow round border rounded-xl border-black w-full"
        ref={ansBoxRef}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```